# how to make a domain object(data) available everywhere? Grails

Tags: templates, grails, dns

> I want to know how to make a domain object or its data available
>   across the system everywhere in grails?
>
> Like sort of syntex do i need to use to make it happen. ATM my app's
>   user object/instance is only available on one of my 3 templates not
>   even any other view.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is available to those views is because your [controller is pushing the model to those views](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#modelsAndViews).  There's nothing stopping you from using your domains from any controller/service you want.

For example, I could do the following:

```
class HomeController {

  def index() {
    def users = User.list()
    render view: "list", model: [users: users]
  }
}
```

Note how I broke away from convention entirely, but it still works.

Comment: Great... Sorry I am fairly new to grails but so excited and keen to master grails...
I didn't quite understand when you said "your controller pushing the model to views"

I understand your example but hows grails determining and accepting user and how the home controller is recognizing user instance?

Comment: I've updated my answer regarding "pushing model to views".  Regarding how the controller can see user...Basic Java; packages.  My code above assumes HomeController and User are in the same package.  If they are not, use an import statement.

Comment: okay I understand your answer but I am still not clear why my app is not letting me do this, I tried page import too... its just my useraccount that i cannot access from most of the pages.
is it dependent on what layout is using or something else?
Thanks